# Making an object's attributes iterable

Tags: python, google-app-engine, iteration

I'm getting returned a list with objects that have multiple attributes like so:

```
results = q.fetch(5)
for p in results:
    print "%s %s, %d inches tall" % (p.first_name, p.last_name, p.height
```

Is it possible to iterate over these attributes so I can do something like `for x in p`. I want to check the value of each one, but I don't want to create a huge block of IF statements.

Comment: It looks like a questionable design to me. It might be better to redesign your program so that you don't need to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I warn against doing this. There are rare exceptions where it's warranted, but almost all the time it's better avoiding this sort of hackish solution. If you want to though, you could use [`vars()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars) to get a dictionary of attributes and iterate through it. As @Nick points out below, App Engine uses properties instead of values to define its members so you have to use [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) to get their values.

```
results = q.fetch(5)
for p in results:
    for attribute in vars(p).keys()
        print '%s = %s' % (attribute, str(getattr(p, attribute)))
```

Demonstration of what `vars()` does:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self, a, b):
...         self.a = a
...         self.b = b
... 
>>> a = A(1, 2)
>>> vars(a)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> for attribute in vars(a).keys():
...     print '%s = %s' % (attribute, str(getattr(a, attribute)))
... 
a = 1
b = 2
```

Comment: This won't work on App Engine, because entity members are properties (descriptors), not just values.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for pointing it out. I've barely used AE. I think this is still worth sticking around for the general python case (IIRC, you can't delete an accepted answer anyway). I've added a note on top though.

Comment: @marcog Fair enough. A version that works in general would be to iterate over the keys of vars(), and call getattr(a, k) on each. It'll iterate over methods and other unwanted cruft in any object though, of course.

Comment: @marcog It ought to, yes. App Engine models are constructed using descriptors, so anything that works on descriptors will work on them. It's probably better practice anyway, since the current snippet bypasses the descriptor protocol, which is probably not the desired outcome.

Comment: @Nick Thanks, you just taught me a good practice. :) Updated my answer with this.

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass the original variable type, and define your own cunning **iter**(self) function, to get what you want.
e.g. to change the way a dictionary iterates:-

```
>>> class mydict(dict):
...    def __iter__(self):
...      for i in self.items():
...          yield i
... 
>>> x = mydict( {'a' : 1, 'b':2 } )
>>> for i in x:
...   print i
... 
('a', 1)
('b', 2)
```

Comment: I've given a more extensive example of making an object iterable at this page:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642219/testing-hsl-colours-ideally-avoiding-red-adjacent-to-green-common-colour-blindn

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of properties on a model class, call `Model.properties()` (or `instance.properties()` - it's a class method). This returns a dictionary mapping property names to Property class instances; you can fetch the value of the properties by doing getattr(instance, name).

If you're using `Expando`, there's also `instance.dynamic_properties()`, which returns a list of dynamically defined properties on that object.

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that the object you get back from `q.fetch(5)` having a `__dict__` attribute, you can simply use `pprint` to display your information.

```
>>> import pprint
>>> results = q.fetch(5)
>>> pprint.pprint(results.__dict__())
```

Or alternatively, if it has something that can be converted to a dictionary, a similar notation would work

```
>>> pprint.pprint(dict(results.dict_like_property))
```

I would suggest though, that this isn't a good approach to take, but it does hold for debugging code easily.